# spread array into object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this bit of code:

```
const calcRowCssClasses = (<string[]>context.dataItem.cssClasses).map(
        (cssClass) => {
          return { [cssClass]: true };
        }
      );
```

This produces the following array of objects:

```
{ "custom-calcrow-1": true },
{ "custom-calcrow-2": true }
```

Now, I have a starting object like this:

```
{ "calcrow": true}
```

The questin is, how can I add the above two entries to the existing object, such that the output will be an object like this:

```
{
  "calcrow": true,
  "custom-calcrow-1": true,
  "custom-calcrow-2": true
}
```

Basically, I would like to spread an array of objects. Doing like this

```
return { calcrow: true, ...calcRowCssClasses };
```

has this result:

```
0: {custom-calcrow-1: true},
1: {custom-calcrow-2: true},
calcrow: true
```

Which isn't the expected result.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not loop through the array and add the `cssClass` property the existing object? `cssClasses.forEach(c => existing[c] = true)`

Comment: use reduce to an object

Comment: Are you producing that array of objects solely to populate the starting object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with spreading the array as parameters.

```
return Object.assign({ calcrow: true }, ...calcRowCssClasses);
```

```js
const calcRowCssClasses = [
    { "custom-calcrow-1": true },
    { "custom-calcrow-2": true }
];

const originalObject = { calcrow: true };

const result = Object.assign(originalObject, ...calcRowCssClasses);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

Comment: @derstauner Or `result = Object.assign({}, originalObject, ...calcRowCssClasses)` if leaving the original object alone is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of .map() use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const context = {dataItem: {cssClasses: ["custom-calcrow-1","custom-calcrow-2"]}};

const calcRowCssClasses = context.dataItem.cssClasses.reduce((ob, cssClass) => (ob[cssClass] = true, ob), {});

console.log({calcrow: true, ...calcRowCssClasses});
```

Comment: Could also just add `calcrow` to the initial value provided to reduce and skip the destructuring entirely.

Answer (score 0):

It seem inefficient to translate `cssClasses` from an array of strings into an array of objects solely to leverage destructing.

Since you're already reaching for an array method, you might as well do it all in one go, skipping the destructuring and passing your partially populated object as the initial value of `Array.prototype.reduce(callback, initialValue)`:

```js
const cssClasses = [
  "custom-calcrow-1",
  "custom-calcrow-2"
];

const output = {
  calcrow: true
};

cssClasses.reduce((accumulator, cssClass) => {
  accumulator[cssClass] = true;
  return accumulator;
}, output);

console.log(output);
```

We're not even gathering the value returned from `reduce()` because we already have a reference to `output`. At this point, you could simply loop instead of using an array method at all:

```js
const cssClasses = [
  "custom-calcrow-1",
  "custom-calcrow-2"
];

const output = {
  calcrow: true
};

for (let cssClass of cssClasses) {
  output[cssClass] = true;
}

console.log(output);
```